# How to loop char in php

Tags: php, char

i need to do a simple loop in php to get char from `a` to `z`.. something like:

```
for($i=0;$i<aNumber;$i++)
   echo "char = ".intToChar($i)."<br>";
```

where aNumber is less then 20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an array of characters easily with [`range` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
$chars = range('a', 'z');
```

Or if you really only want to print them:

```
echo implode('<br />', range('a', 'z'));
```

Comment: Range was very helpful. Thank you. Starting to like PHP more and more

Answer (score 2):

You need understand ASCII table. See in [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Codes for `A - Z` is `65 - 90` and `a - z` is `97 - 122`.

```
for($i = 97; $i <= 122; $i++)
    echo chr($i);
```

Answer (score 1):

I SOLVED IN THIS WAY:

```
$i = 0;
$char = 'a';
$aNumber = xx;
while($i<$aNumber){
    echo $char."<br>";
    $char++;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: You must try your best shot before making a question.

Answer (score 0):

To return character specified by ASCII code/number use [chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) function. Since you want to loop from 0 to 20, then you need to add 97 to `$i`, 97 is ASCII code for letter `a`:

```
for($i=0;$i<$aNumber;$i++)
   echo "char = ".chr($i+97)."<br>"; // + 97 because it is ASCII 'a'
```

If you just want to loop through those letters you can do it like this:

```
for($i = ord('a'); $i < ord('z'); $i++)
   echo "char = ".chr($i)."<br>";
```

Additionally if you just want to get array of those characters you can use [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function:

```
$chars = range('a', 'z');
```